# How to eliminate string;# prepended to list field in three-state workflow notification?

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, sharepoint-workflow

I need to include two list values, [Office] and [Position ID] in a three-state workflow Task Title, which only allows selecting one column via dropdown.  SharePoint Designer is not an option.  Office is a choice column, while Position ID is single line of text.  So, I had the idea to combine the two columns into a calculated column.  This works fine for views, and displays as expected.  However, when included as a list field in the Task Title of a three-state workflow, SharePoint prepends string;# to the calculated column value.  Is there any way to prevent or workaround this?  I have tried various concatenation methods within the calculated column formula, but it does not seem to have any effect on the workflow notifications.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could reproduce your issue:

[image]

However this is a hard coded workflow and we cannot change it.

Currently we could only manually remove the string;# via editing the task title in related task list.